# Load Entire Neo4j Database into Linkurious's SigmaJS

Tags: neo4j, sigma.js, linkurious

How can I load an entire Neo4j database into Linkurious's [SigmaJS Graph API](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/wiki/Graph-API)? On that page, I don't see any methods that describe how to import a database in its entirety -- only how to build out a graph manually by adding nodes and edges. I suspect that the read() function almost does what I want (reading in an object), but it is unclear in what format I must supply this object in.

It would be great to be able to simply pass in the graph.db folder within my Neo4j folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the idea of the library correct.  It's a general purpose library to display graph visualizations and not specific to any graph database.  I also suspect that it's not going to effectively hold your entire database (it depends on the size).  The idea of it is to load in the required subset of the data and make it easy to display and work with that data.

The linksurious team could correct me if I'm wrong here, though ;)

Comment: I can't speak for linkurious, but the goal of sigma.js is exactly that.
For information there a plugin to charge sigma.js instance from a cypher query : https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/load-neo4j-cypher-query.html#L74-L82